# How to connect a printer to a router that is behind another router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, printer

[image: Network Layout]

I have a central wireless router (M1, TP-Link C6 Model) connected to a modem (via ethernet cable) to the internet. I then connected two other wireless routers- S1 and S2 (both are D-Link AX1500 Models), to M1 using ethernet cables as shown in the network layout figure.

I have a laptop connected to S1 and a wireless printer connected to S2.

I am not able to find the printer in the network on my laptop.

How to route this properly so as to discover the printer in the laptop?

P.S. Please correct me if there are mistakes in the terminologies used.

Comment: You appear to have too many subnets. Try to reduce subnets to 1.  Then hook your printer up to the network (wired preferred, wireless less good) and install driver on any machines you wish.

Comment: Thanks, John. I am completely new to networking. How to convert multiple subnets into one?

Comment: Pick a base router (and subnet) and then for each other router, see if you can set it up to the base subnet. I do this here and it works fine.

Comment: John was faster :-) The fastest and easiest way just now is simply change the subnet mask to 255.255.0.0 in all systems. This way you don't have to change the current IP addresses.

Comment: I checked the subnet mask for all routers. It's configured as 255.255.255.0

Comment: You then need to look in the wireless router settings and see if you can make it 192.168.95.x assuming .95 is you selected subnet

Comment: Which router should I make it to .95- M1 or S1?

Comment: I set the IP for S1 as 192.168.95.2 and M1 as 192.168.95.3. Then I tried to ping 192.168.95.150 (Printer). It gives request time out.

Comment: You can make any router the base .95 network. Make sure that all are on .95 now. Make sure each device has Network Discovery enabled (and probably File/Print

Comment: Thanks John! It finally worked. I did try that but the other router were creating their own sub-networks. So I switched on the bridge mode in D-Link settings in both routers and it worked!